# Why are my for loops not incrementing properly in java?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have been trying to solve this for several hours: why do j and the other variables change when the l loop hasn't even completed yet? Here is my code:

```
public class main
{

        public static void main (String[] args)
        {

        String name=args[0];
        double a=Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        double b=Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
        double c=Double.parseDouble(args[3]);
        double d=Double.parseDouble(args[4]);

        //for complexes
        for (double i = -a; i<=a; i++){
            for (double j = -b; j<=b; j++){
                for (double k = -c; k<=c; k++){
                    for (double l = -d; l<=d; l++){
                        complex c1 = new complex (i, j);
                        complex c2 = new complex (k, l);
                        System.out.println(c1+"; "+c2);

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//And the complex class:


public class complex {
    private static double c;
    private static double n;

    public complex(double c, double n){
        this.c=c;
        this.n=n;
    }
    public String toString(){
        if ((n==0)&&(c==0))
            return "0";
        if (n==0)
            return ""+c;
        if (c==0)
            return ""+n+"i";
        else return ""+c+"+"+n+"i";
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
ect.
```

But the output is supposed to be

```
-1.0-2.0i; -1.0-2.0i
-1.0-2.0i; -1.0-1.0i
-1.0-2.0i; -1.0
-1.0-2.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0-2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-1.0-2.0i; -2.0i
ect.
```

But anything in the complex class shouldn't matter, right?  Cause even if I used variables of the same name they shouldn't be accessible from outside of their class, right? 
Thanks so much for any help!  I've asked other people as well and nobody has been able to spot my error either, so anything is much appreciated.

EDIT:

I didn't post the full output before.  Here is the output I get:

```
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+-2.0i; -1.0+-2.0i
-1.0+-1.0i; -1.0+-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
0; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+-2.0i; 1.0+-2.0i
1.0+-1.0i; 1.0+-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
```

And here is what I should be getting:

```
    -1.0-2.0i; -1.0-2.0i
    -1.0-2.0i; -1.0-1.0i
-1.0-2.0i; -1.0
-1.0-2.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0-2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-1.0-2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0-2.0i; -1.0i
-1.0-2.0i; 0
-1.0-2.0i; 1.0i
-1.0-2.0i; 2.0i
-1.0-2.0i; 1.0-2.0i
-1.0-2.0i; 1.0-1.0i
-1.0-2.0i; 1.0
-1.0-2.0i; 1.0+1.0i
-1.0-2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0-1.0i; -1.0-2.0i
-1.0-1.0i; -1.0-1.0i
-1.0-1.0i; -1.0
-1.0-1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0-1.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-1.0-1.0i; -2.0i
-1.0-1.0i; -1.0i
-1.0-1.0i; 0
-1.0-1.0i; 1.0i
-1.0-1.0i; 2.0i
-1.0-1.0i; 1.0-2.0i
-1.0-1.0i; 1.0-1.0i
-1.0-1.0i; 1.0
-1.0-1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
-1.0-1.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0; -1.0-2.0i
-1.0; -1.0-1.0i
-1.0; -1.0
-1.0; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0; -1.0+2.0i
-1.0; -2.0i
-1.0; -1.0i
-1.0; 0
-1.0; 1.0i
-1.0; 2.0i
-1.0; 1.0-2.0i
-1.0; 1.0-1.0i
-1.0; 1.0
-1.0; 1.0+1.0i
-1.0; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0-2.0i
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0-1.0i
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-1.0+1.0i; -2.0i
-1.0+1.0i; -1.0i
-1.0+1.0i; 0
-1.0+1.0i; 1.0i
-1.0+1.0i; 2.0i
-1.0+1.0i; 1.0-2.0i
-1.0+1.0i; 1.0-1.0i
-1.0+1.0i; 1.0
-1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
-1.0+1.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0-2.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0-1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -2.0i
-1.0+2.0i; -1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; 0
-1.0+2.0i; 1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; 2.0i
-1.0+2.0i; 1.0-2.0i
-1.0+2.0i; 1.0-1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; 1.0
-1.0+2.0i; 1.0+1.0i
-1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -1.0-2.0i
-2.0i; -1.0-1.0i
-2.0i; -1.0
-2.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-2.0i; -2.0i
-2.0i; -1.0i
-2.0i; 0
-2.0i; 1.0i
-2.0i; 2.0i
-2.0i; 1.0-2.0i
-2.0i; 1.0-1.0i
-2.0i; 1.0
-2.0i; 1.0+1.0i
-2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0-2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0-1.0i
-1.0i; -1.0
-1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
-1.0i; -1.0+2.0i
-1.0i; -2.0i
-1.0i; -1.0i
-1.0i; 0
-1.0i; 1.0i
-1.0i; 2.0i
-1.0i; 1.0-2.0i
-1.0i; 1.0-1.0i
-1.0i; 1.0
-1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
-1.0i; 1.0+2.0i
0; -1.0-2.0i
0; -1.0-1.0i
0; -1.0
0; -1.0+1.0i
0; -1.0+2.0i
0; -2.0i
0; -1.0i
0; 0
0; 1.0i0
0; 2.0i
0; 1.0-2.0i
0; 1.0-1.0i
0; 1.0
0; 1.0+1.0i
0; 1.0+2.0i
1.0i; -1.0-2.0i
1.0i; -1.0-1.0i
1.0i; -1.0
1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
1.0i; -1.0+2.0i
1.0i; -2.0i
1.0i; -1.0i
1.0i; 0
1.0i; 1.0i
1.0i; 2.0i
1.0i; 1.0-2.0i
1.0i; 1.0-1.0i
1.0i; 1.0
1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0i; 1.0+2.0i
2.0i; -1.0-2.0i
2.0i; -1.0-1.0i
2.0i; -1.0
2.0i; -1.0+1.0i
2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
2.0i; -2.0i
2.0i; -1.0i
2.0i; 0
2.0i; 1.0i
2.0i; 2.0i
2.0i; 1.0-2.0i
2.0i; 1.0-1.0i
2.0i; 1.0
2.0i; 1.0+1.0i
2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
1.0-2.0i; -1.0-2.0i
1.0-2.0i; -1.0-1.0i
1.0-2.0i; -1.0
1.0-2.0i; -1.0+1.0i
1.0-2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
1.0-2.0i; -2.0i
1.0-2.0i; -1.0i
1.0-2.0i; 0
1.0-2.0i; 1.0i
1.0-2.0i; 2.0i
1.0-2.0i; 1.0-2.0i
1.0-2.0i; 1.0-1.0i
1.0-2.0i; 1.0
1.0-2.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0-2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
1.0-1.0i; -1.0-2.0i
1.0-1.0i; -1.0-1.0i
1.0-1.0i; -1.0
1.0-1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
1.0-1.0i; -1.0+2.0i
1.0-1.0i; -2.0i
1.0-1.0i; -1.0i
1.0-1.0i; 0
1.0-1.0i; 1.0i
1.0-1.0i; 2.0i
1.0-1.0i; 1.0-2.0i
1.0-1.0i; 1.0-1.0i
1.0-1.0i; 1.0
1.0-1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0-1.0i; 1.0+2.0i
1.0; -1.0-2.0i
1.0; -1.0-1.0i
1.0; -1.0
1.0; -1.0+1.0i
1.0; -1.0+2.0i
1.0; -2.0i
1.0; -1.0i
1.0; 0
1.0; 1.0i
1.0; 2.0i
1.0; 1.0-2.0i
1.0; 1.0-1.0i
1.0; 1.0
1.0; 1.0+1.0i
1.0; 1.0+2.0i
1.0+1.0i; -1.0-2.0i
1.0+1.0i; -1.0-1.0i
1.0+1.0i; -1.0
1.0+1.0i; -1.0+1.0i
1.0+1.0i; -1.0+2.0i
1.0+1.0i; -2.0i
1.0+1.0i; -1.0i
1.0+1.0i; 0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0i
1.0+1.0i; 2.0i
1.0+1.0i; 1.0-2.0i
1.0+1.0i; 1.0-1.0i
1.0+1.0i; 1.0
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+1.0i; 1.0+2.0i
1.0+2.0i; -1.0-2.0i
1.0+2.0i; -1.0-1.0i
1.0+2.0i; -1.0
1.0+2.0i; -1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; -1.0+2.0i
1.0+2.0i; -2.0i
1.0+2.0i; -1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 0
1.0+2.0i; 1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 2.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0-2.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0-1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+1.0i
1.0+2.0i; 1.0+2.0i
```

Comment: Because the variables I am initializing them to are doubles, and they have to be the same type, right?

Comment: I see what you're after. It can be a source of error or imprecise looping.

Answer (score 0):

*why do j and the other variables change when the l loop hasn't even completed yet?* 
its because j,k and l are initalized each time when I increases.

in this

```
for (double j = -b; j<=b; j++){
            for (double k = -c; k<=c; k++){
                for (double l = -d; l<=d; l++){
```

here when `i=-a then j=-b,k=-c and l=-d`
now when then the i is incremented then also `i=-a then j=-b,k=-c and l=-d`

Comment: Are you saying each time the loop j, k, and l get reassigned the current values of their counterparts?

Comment: @BobbyDigital I am talking about outermost loop         for (double i = -a; i<=a; i++){

Comment: My eyes must be failing me; I don't see it. The initialization part of a for loop only gets called once; right?

Comment: Actually, this is what I want.  I didn't post the full outputs, but the outputs are many lines long.

Comment: @BobbyDigital lets take a=10 and i is an int.So the outermost loop will continue for 20 times.Right?

Comment: @user2943867 why you are not using for (int i=-a;....) why for(double i=-a)
I am seeing this type for the first time

Comment: Alright, I see what you're saying now, for some reason I thought you were saying the initialization runs *each* loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're after this behaviour:

```
for (double i = -a; i<=a; i++){
    for (double j = -b; j<=b; j++){
        complex c1 = new complex (i, j);
        System.out.println(c1);
    }
}
for (double k = -c; k<=c; k++){
    for (double l = -d; l<=d; l++){
        complex c2 = new complex (k, l);
        System.out.println(c2);
    }
}
```